# Update to BehaviorSubject not being reflected when targeted from my service file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using `*ngIf` to toggle between 3 components inside of my `HomeComponent`.  At the moment I'm focused on the relationship between 2 of them which are the `ProductListComponent` and `ProductDetailComponent`.  Inside the `ProductListComponent` I have a `ProductListItemComponent` for iterating each product. Inside of my`HomeService` I'm using a variable of type `BehaviorSubject` to subscribe to in the `HomeComponent` for the `*ngIf` conditions to react to.  The setup in my `HomeService` looks like this.

```
//variable with the initial value
private FrameToggle: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('product-list');

//variable for watching BehaviorSubject as Observable
CurrentToggle = this.FrameToggle.asObservable();

//function for setting the BehaviorSubject
setFrameToggle(page: string){ this.FrameToggle.next(page); }
```

Inside of the `ProductListItemComponent` and `ProductDetailComponent` I import the `HomeService` as a provider and target the `setFrameToggle()` function like this.

```
sendPageToggle(page: string){ this.homeService.setFrameToggle(page); }
```

Inside the templates I trigger it with a button like this

```
<button (click)="sendPageToggle('value-to-trigger-desired-component'")>some text</button>
```

So far it all works and the appropriate components are toggled on and off when the buttons are clicked.

When I moved forwards with having data fetched in the `ProductDetailComponentService` to be provided for the `ProductDetailComponent` I ran into asynchronous issues because the `ProductDetailComponent` was loading before the data was fetched.

I addressed the issue by importing the `ProductDetailComponentService` into the `ProductListItemComponent` as a provider and import the `HomeService` into the `ProductDetailComponentService` and use an `async` function to fetch the data first then set the `FrameToggle` variable in the `HomeService`.  The function looks like this

```
async prepareData(key: string, page: string){
    await (()=> {this.ProductData = this.setData(page);})();
    this.homeService.setFrameToggle(key);
}
```

I created a function in my `ProductListComponent` to call this function which works, however the component doesn't toggle as it does when calling the `setFrameToggle()` function from the inside the component.

I added a `console.log()` targeting the `ProductData` variable inside the `prepareData()` function and saw the data was successfully loaded.  I then added a `console.log()` to the `setFrameToggle()` function in the `HomeService` to log the value passed in from the `prepareData()` function in the `ProductDetailComponentService` which also successfully returns the result.

I even duplicated the function eliminating the `async` away from it and deleting the first part so the function only calls to the `setFrameToggle()` function in the `HomeService` just to see if maybe there was some hidden `Promise<string>` confusion of some sort effecting the type of the value being sent yet the components still didn't toggle.  I have the `HomeService` properly imported into the `ProductDetailComponent`'s module as a provider, I have no clue what's causing this to not work.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm going to upvote this just because you really took your time to explain the question, but if you can write a small summary will be great :)

Comment: it's much better if you can provide minimal stackbitz demo

Comment: ok I've been sitting here for over 2 hours trying to get it built on stackblitz and it winds up getting stuck at `connecting to dev server` and I have no clue where and how the problem starts.  I could've been trying to figure out the problem on my own machine smh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this

> Inside of the ProductListItemComponent and ProductDetailComponent I
>   import the HomeService as a provider

I would guess you are dealing with multiple instances of the HomeService.  Whenever you mark a service as a provider to a component or a module it scopes it to that component or module so it is no longer a Singleton for the application but is instead scoped at the level you added it.  So if I add a service to my component providers array then each instance of that component will get a different instance of that service.

The easiest way to verify this (assuming you are using an Angular version that supports this) would be to change your HomeService to inject at the root and remove it from all providers arrays in any module or component setup:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeService{
```

Alternatively just double check that your homeService is only in one provider array and it should be at a level above all of your components that are interacting with it.

Comment: should I still have it imported into my component and set to a private variable inside the constructor?

Comment: now that I think about it, I ran into another minor problem nearly a week ago with using services inside of other services which is when I learned that we now needed to import them into that component's module and add it to the provider's array there to avoid problems, which means I'd need to have it imported into multiple modules.  Is this something different or does it still contribute to my problem?

Comment: Yes your constructors will all be the same.  You just have to be careful with how you setup your service providers.  Depending on how you're using the service it sometimes should be setup as a provider in a component and other times provided in the root or the module. From the information I have it's hard to tell how yours should be setup.  If your running into issues where you've set something on the service but it's not being reflected in other places when pulling it from the service 9 times out of 10 it is because you have multiple instances of the service and don't realize it.